# Adsense in IE 8 - not displaying correctly

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, adsense, ie8-compatibility-mode, ie-developer-tools

I have been building a forum using mybb. I have used Adsense to incorporate a couple of advertisements into the site but they are not displaying correctly in IE8.  They look fine in IE10 (and IE8 when in compatibility mode), Chrome and Firefox. The issue is that the advertisements in IE8 appear to be misaligned by 1 or 2 pixels.

In development mode, I have identifed a line which I believe is created by Adsense as it's not part of my original code, which appears to cause the issue.

It is `display: inline-table`.  If I uncheck this, the ads on the site appear aligned with the content. But as this is a dynamically created bit of code, I can't edit it... (or can I?)

Can anyone help me resolve this issue and get my advertisements in line with the rest of my content?

Edit:

The code I get from Google Adsense is:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- ShowThreadSideSquare -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:200px;height:200px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-6454993037050681"
     data-ad-slot="7524464050"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

When I look at it through the development screen in IE, it has expanded to much more, but this is the line with the `inline-table` comment which seems to make it unaligned in IE8. But I can't seem to edit it as it's not in my source code...

```
<ins style="width: 200px; 
          height: 200px; 
          padding-top: 0px; 
          padding-right: 0px; 
          padding-bottom: 0px; 
          padding-left: 0px; 
          margin-top: 0px; 
          margin-right: 0px; 
          margin-bottom: 0px; 
          margin-left: 0px; 
          border-top-color: currentColor; 
          border-right-color: currentColor; 
          border-bottom-color: currentColor; 
          border-left-color: currentColor; 
          border-top-width: medium; 
          border-right-width: medium; 
          border-bottom-width: medium; 
          border-left-width: medium; 
          border-top-style: none; 
          border-right-style: none; 
          border-bottom-style: none; 
          border-left-style: none; 
          display: inline-table; 
          visibility: visible; 
          position: relative;">
```

Comment: can you show us a little bit of the code that creates the advertisements please

Comment: The new version use inline-block for responsive Ad. In Ie8, this shows very bad. Looking for a solution. The code is in Div but no use. Overflow:hidden on `<ins>` can save by not making page littered.

Answer (score 0):

what I would do to fix this is take the code and put it inside of a `div` and add styling to the div so that the div will align.  it should separate the code enough to make it align itself.

if you provide a JSFiddle I might be able to help you more, but I think you have the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

In the code that you get from Google Adsense  you should change the style from:

```
<ins style="display:inline-block;width:200px;height:200px" > </ins>
```

to:

```
<ins style="display:inline-block;width:200px;height:200px; margin:0 auto;" > </ins>
```

the second set of code that you are showing is how IE(8) renders the HTML/CSS in compatibility mode,  you need to specify how the browser should display the HTML and if you don't specify some of the properties they don't automatically get assigned, some browsers will assume certain things though.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is way old, but I had the same problem and this is the solution..

Just add this to your CSS file, which will override the inline-table which is causing the problem.

```
ins
{
display: inline-block !important;
}
```